# How to ship an openfl desktop (windows) application

Tags: haxe, openfl, nme

I created a haxe project using openfl. I can build and run the project on my own desktop using `lime test windows`.

Now how do I actually ship this project to other users?

I tried simply zipping the binary output created by running the command above. When I then unpack this zip on a different computer and start the executable file it will complain that I'm missing certain .dll files (more specifically the libstdc++-6.dll file).

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a direct answer to your question, a solution to this issue would be to compile through another software/tool, such as FlashDevelop.

For a few versions already, FlashDevelop includes an App manager feature that allows you to easily install the latest versions of Haxe, Lime & OpenFl (in an all-in-one package), and compile for all the Haxe/Lime/OpenFl targets seamlessly by just switching a value in a drop-down menu.

This allowed me to compile without any problems native C++ or Neko versions of my projects, thus embedding all the necessary files that could be zipped and sent to other computers.